# Removing Apache from Debian 5

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, vps

I had Debian 5 installed on my VPS but I found that it came with apache2 already up and running. I tried

```
apt-get remove apache2
```

but it said that apache2 wasn't running. I checked top and yep, there it was. So then I turned it off.

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

which worked fine and shut the daemon down. However, I still can't remove it. I tried `aptitude remove` but it says that it isn't installed.

What is going on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `apt-get remove apache2-utils`.

In Debian 5, Apache is split into multiple packages:

1. apache2
2. apache2-mpm-prefork (or apache2-mpm-worker or apache2-mpm-event)
3. apache2.2-common
4. apache2-utils

There are interdependencies: (1) depends on (2), which depends on (3), which depends on (4).  Therefore, removing (4) causes all of them to be removed.  (The apache2 package doesn't contain much in itself; it just exists so that you can do `apt-get install apache2` to conveniently install all of those packages.)

Comment: Ah, perfect! Cleaned it right up.

Comment: I can verify that this applies to Debian 6, too.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your VPS didn't came with Apache installed via apt-get. See if you can find the binaries in /usr/local, which is a telltale sign of it being compiled from source.

I can't find a good reason for doing this... and I don't like the sound of it...

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to remove the package via `apt` or `synaptic`, it's likely that apache was (for some unforesaken reason) installed from a binary tarball or possibly from source. In this case, there's probably not much you can do aside from manually deleting the files associated with apache.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove everything apache related is to run

```
apt-get remove apache2*
```